# PHP Imageline() Brush Tip & Smooth Line

Tags: php, image, image-processing, gd

So, I'm having a problem with the result of PHP's `imageline()` function. I should preface with the fact that some lines are coming from an HTML5 canvas. The first problem is that the resulting lines are rather choppier than they should be. Now, `imageantialias()` fixed the issue of choppy lines, however the lines lose the thickness they're supposed to have.

The second issue is that the brush tip is likewise rather uneven, as opposed to what they are on the canvas, which is a rounded tip.

Here are the images for reference (it might not be as noticeable on non-mobile devices, which they were made from):

[image: What image should look like]
<sub>(source: [socialcu.be](http://socialcu.be/Images/correct.png))</sub>

[image: What image actually turns out as]

Does anyone know how to fix these issues? :-)

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using to generate this from the canvas, and some sample data?